# How to fix "ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value." when running a batch file

Tags: batch-file, registry

I am trying to run a simple batch command -

```
reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002\Functions" /f
```

and it is returning the error "ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value." I know the value name is there (I'm looking at it in the Registry Editor).

I've tried copy/pasting the direct path into the command. I've also tried removing the quotes and running the batch as administrator. I know I can simply right-click the value and click delete, but I may have to do this on many machines and it would be a huge time saver to not have to navigate down in the registry.

Comment: Are you running under an elevated (administrative) user account when executing the batch file? Have you opened the command window with administrative rights?

Comment: Yes and yes. Same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Is it in WOW6432Node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not deleting a registry key named:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002\Functions
```

You're deleting a registry value, named: `Functions` which exists under the key named `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002`.

To perform the task you therefore need to use the correct syntax:

```bat
Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002" /V "Functions" /F > NUL
```

You would also need to run the script 'as Administrator', to prevent an `Access is denied` message.